# How to create a non-trainable tensorflow Variable object inside layer call

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to create a tf.Variable inside a custom Keras layer's call method. My current method is:

```
    def __init__(self, filters, conv_size, lag, **kwargs):
        super(Upscaler, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(1, 128, 128, 3),
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.run = True

    @tf.function
    def call(self, x):
        if self.run:
            self.outs = tf.Variable(x, trainable=False)
            self.run=False
        else:
            self.outs.assign(x)
        self.outs.assign(self.outs+self.w)
        return self.outs
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error. I think it is because the tf.Variable `self.outs` does not provide gradients, but it should not have them if `trainable=False`. I am not sure if I should pass some random gradients if it does not use them (and if so, then how do I do this?) I can't use `tf.constant` because of some other complications. The error is:

````
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['upscaler/Variable:0', 'upscaler/Variable:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'upscaler/Variable:0' shape=(100, 5, 5, 3) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'upscaler/Variable:0' shape=(100, 5, 5, 3) dtype=float32>)).```
````

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example

Comment: How you are computing the gradient for this class? by Gradient.Tape() method or model.fit()?

Comment: I am using model.fit(). I added a reproducible example.